# Handling the Callback from animoto videos

Tags: ruby

I am using Animoto API to create all the images into video.

As per the animoto documentation I have used " 
job = Animoto::Jobs::DirectingAndRendering.load(JSON.parse(request.body))"

for handling the call back from anomoto API but it is throwing error called

"uninitialized constant Animoto::Jobs"

Anybody has any idea about his. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Animoto, but your error comes from a missing Ruby library defining Animoto::Jobs class.
This can be resolved by requiring the Ruby file defining this class, using `require '<NameOfRubyFile>'` before using it (usually at the top of your .rb file).

You can try the following:

1. Check the way Animoto's API is meant to be included. Some libraries will just need 1 require that will then include plenty of other files (ie. `require 'animoto'`). Other libraries will ask you to require each individual file manually (ie. `require 'animoto/main'; require 'animoto/jobs'`). I would say that Animoto documentation should tell.
2. Check the `require` lines used by other projects using `Animoto::Jobs` class.
3. If Animoto respects some Ruby standards, you can try blindly `require 'animoto/jobs'`
4. If you have access to Animoto's source code, try looking for the class definition among its files. The definition should look like `class Jobs` or `class Animoto::Jobs`. Grep this in the source files, and require the matching one.

Maybe a specialist of Animoto's library will be able to point you directly to the missing require.